# c# Serial Port Names

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I want to control microcontroller using serial port.

How can I get the name of the value in the index I selected from the checkbox? For example, index 0 has com 4. I want to make it print com4 when I select index 0.

And how can I get the id or name of the connected device from the list of connected devices instead of names like com1,com2?

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows;

namespace Afv
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
        String [] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        int _selectedPortIndex;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            portDetect();
        }

        private void portDetect()
        {
            if(ports != null)
            {
                foreach(String port in ports)
                {
                    portList.Items.Add(port);
                }
            }
        }

        private void portList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _selectedPortIndex = portList.SelectedIndex;
            Console.WriteLine(_selectedPortIndex);
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
            serialPort.Close();
        }

        private void connectionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(_selectedPortIndex != -1)
                {
                    serialPort.PortName = _selectedPortIndex.ToString();
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no information about "connected devices" to the serial port. Such information needs to be papered by other means. If you could get it programmatically, it would be Friendly Name. [How to get "FriendlyName" of a Device ContainerID (SPDRP_BASE_CONTAINERID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197894/how-to-get-34friendlyname34-of-a-device-containeri.html)

Comment: I am also a novice in this area, you can first take out the "ID or name of the device" according to the if judgment and display it through the event